# Should Jenkins apply round robin if nodes have the same label?

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins it is possible to assign labels to nodes, e.g. somenode to nodes and then one could call somenode in the pipeline and then Jenkins will run the build on some of the nodes.

**Problem**

The assumption was that Jenkins would apply round robin, i.e. the number of builds that is run on node 1 2 3 4 and 5 is equal, but actually the majority, I.e. more than 90 percent is run on node four.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding a source to confirm or refute this, but I believe Jenkins has a preference towards scheduling builds on the node where the build ran most recently.  So no, it doesn't do round robin.

Comment: I think you might find the answer to your question in this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024007/how-can-i-modify-the-load-balancing-behavior-jenkins-uses-to-control-slaves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jayhendren indicated that:

> I think you might find the answer to your question in this SO post:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/q/11024007/2777965